# Display 01/01/1999 instead of 01/01/1999 00:00:00 in TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a TextBox which displays this format '01/01/1999 00:00:00' but my record has a `date` type not  a `datetime`.
Thank you

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 7):

> my recors have a date type not datetime

.Net `DateTime` has Date and Time together. If your record has only date then you will see the time set at `00:00:00`. To display only date you can use:

```
textBox.Text = yourDateObject.ToShortDateString();
```

Or you can pass custom format to `ToString` like:

```
textBox.Text = yourDateObject.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For more info see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Meryem, what ever object you are holding `Date` in.